# How to add Swagger UI to Apache Camel Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, swagger-ui

I'm using [Apache Camel Spring Boot](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/next/index.html) to create a REST service with [Camel REST DSL](https://camel.apache.org/manual/rest-dsl.html) and documented with OpenApi.

Now I'm following the [rest-openapi-springdoc](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/tree/main/rest-openapi-springdoc) official example and can successfully access the OpenApi docs and all the Rest routes are working fine. The Swagger UI should be avaliable at `/swagger-ui.html`, but It's returning a 404 error when I try to access it.

How can I make swagger UI work with Apache Camel Spring Boot? I'm using Java 17 and my code is the same as the official example: `https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/blob/main/rest-openapi-springdoc/README.adoc`

Answer (score 0):

There is the camel-springdoc-starter
https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot/tree/main/components-starter/camel-springdoc-starter

To add swagger-ui in Spring Boot then this is a general SB question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @claus-ibsen, but this is already being used in the project. [Here is the pom](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/blob/16feb3de9c9e9e9cbe1d4e73a45aabbbd896fe38/rest-openapi-springdoc/pom.xml#LL79C13-L79C13). 
 I'm try the [official example] (https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/blob/main/rest-openapi-springdoc), but It's returning a 404 error when hit `/swagger-ui.html`.